# Как мне лучше сделать изображение пользователя в Layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity-3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне лучше передавать из бд путь изображения профиля, у меня эта картинка(та что справа) находится в Layout, что значит что она будет на всех страницах сайта. Я думал использовать тут частичное представление, но у меня с ними опыта не много, и я не очень понимаю каким образом я смогу кидать в неё(частичное представление), путь к изображению. Для меняя остаётся вариант использования сервиса, то-есть создать свой сервис который будет возвращать путь к изображению, и заинжектить его в Layout. Но мне такое решение не нравится, и кажется неправильным. Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне лучше сделать.

---

Я нашёл решения своей проблемы, так что оставлю этот тут.

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/passing-data-to-view-master-pages-cs

Не знаю почему я раньше не мог найти эту статью, видимо плохо искал.

Comment: Подскажите, я правильно понимаю, что Вам надо получить из базы путь к картинке и передать его представлению?

Comment: Да, но это мастер страница и я не очень понимаю как лучше перекинуть путь к картинке

Comment: Мне видится два варианта: создать базовую View-модель, в которой, кроме всего будет и путь к картинке профиля и все остальные View-модели наследовать от неё. Второй -- передавать путь через ViewBag.

Comment: @SerafimProzorov Да, но так и так придётся передавать и ViewBag и модель во все контроллеры, что 100% неправильно.

Comment: Почему Вы считаете, что это неправильно? Почти у любой вьюшки есть View-модель, Вам просто надо в базовом классе создать свойство, например, ProfileImagePath для неё и унаследовать остальные от этого класса. Естественно, что в каждом методе контроллера устанавливать свойство ProfileImagePath руками не следует, для этого стоит создать абстрактную фабрику. В случае со ViewBag значение действительно придётся устанавливать в каждом методе, поэтому вариант не самый лучший. Кроме этого есть вопрос: скажите, а картинки хранятся где-то на ваших серверах, если да, то можно сделать всё ещё проще.

Comment: @SerafimProzorov Картинки хранятся у меня в папке с сайтом.